# How to print from .asl file(ACPI files) Methods to serial console?

Tags: acpi

have to debug .asl file, How can print from .asl file(ACPI files) Methods to serial console.
Method gets called from OS kernel driver at runtime.

Comment: The standard methods. Read https://www.slideshare.net/suselab/acpi-debugging-from-linux-kernel, https://acpica.org/sites/acpica/files/asl_tutorial_v20190625.pdf. OS will print you on serial in case you configured it to do so.

Comment: I see below Printf description example in acpi spec6.3, but when I call this getting syntax error ==> unexpected PARSEOP_NAMESEG, expecting '(' ^                     
                                                                                                                                 
The following ASL example uses Printf to write a formatted string with the values of Arg0, Arg1, Arg2, and
Arg3 to the Debug Object.
 Printf ("%o: Unexpected value for %o, %o at line %o",
 Arg0, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)